# Completeness of order statistics for normal setup

Tags: self-learning, statistical-inference, order-statistics, sufficient-statistics

Suppose we have iid $X_1,\ldots, X_n\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where $\mu$ is unknown.

Let $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)},\ldots,X_{(n)}$be the order statistics.

Is the order statistics $\textbf{complete sufficient}$ when

$A)$ $\sigma$ is known ?

$B)$ $\sigma$ is unknown ?

Comment: The whole set of order statistics or each one individually? The whole set is sufficient, but not complete. Individually they aren't sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is phrased like a textbook exercise and you haven't said anything about what particular difficulties you've had with it, I will keep this short.

Note that $\operatorname{E}(X_{(n)} - X_{(1)}) = a\sigma,$ for some $a>0,$ and although finding the value of $a$ may be a lot of work, (the following is crucial) you do not need to know $\mu$ or $\sigma$ to find $a.$ In other words, $a$ is "known". Note that $X_{(n)} - X_{(1)} - a\sigma$ is therefore a **statistic** if $\sigma$ is known, but not if $\sigma$ is not known, and its expected value is $0.$

That should get you started on this.

As for sufficiency, the complete set of order statistics from i.i.d. observations is always sufficient.

Comment: you meant to say that $X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}$ is an ancillary statistic?

Comment: @Querty : $X_{(n)} - X_{(1)}$ is an ancillary statistic if $\sigma$ is known, but not if $\sigma$ is unknown.

Comment: So I get that the order statistics is complete for known sigma. However i am still in dark about the unknown $\sigma$ part.